# Error in event handler for webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders/2: Error: Invalid value for argument 4. Property '$$state': Unexpected property

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-webrequest

I'm writing a chrome extension and I'm getting this error

```
Error in event handler for webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders/2: Error: Invalid value for argument 4. Property '$$state': Unexpected property
```

I'm not even sure where it's coming from so not sure what code snippet to provide to get started.

Any idea how I should even read this error message? What does the "/2" in "onBeforeSendHeaders/2" mean?

Perhaps there's a clue in my listener (simplified for our sake. I'm really doing an ajax fetch to get data before returning a promise of the headers)

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      resolve({requestHeaders: [name:'authorization',value:'...']}
    });
},
{urls: [ "<all_urls>" ]},
['requestHeaders','blocking']);
```

Bonus question. The listener doesn't seem to be adding the header I injected when resolved in a Promise. It works if I just return {requestHeaders: ...} directly.

Thoughts?

Comment: Chrome API is callback-based and does not work with neither Promise nor async/await. It should be trivial to find lots of working examples, here's the official ones: [samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:webrequest).

Comment: @wOxxOm what would you suggest if I need to do some async stuff before returning the modified headers?

Comment: Ah, well, you're out of luck in Chrome then. You can find various workarounds here on StackOverflow though.

Comment: Can I use browser.webRequest in a chrome extension? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeSendHeaders#Examples

Comment: No, you can't, of course. Chrome doesn't implement WebExtensions API.

Comment: ok thx. i'm new to this. i read that WebExtension API was somewhat compatible with Chrome, but I guess not the other way around then